# How to `cd` with word in the middle of a folder?

Tags: command-line, cd-command

I have workspace with many folders which all are consisted of long paths. For example:

```
|- workspace
|-- this.is.very.long.name.context
|-- this.is.another.long.path.authors
|-- // 20 more folders
|-- this.is.folder.with.too.many.characters.folder
```

They all start with same phase (`this.is`) which in my real case is 20 characters long and they mostly differ in last sequence. Is there any way to quickly navigate through them using `cd` command? Any wild characters like `?`?

Comment: If this happens often you may want to give `fzf` a shot.  I rarely just `cd` anymore; with `fzf` installed, typing `Alt-C` and then a few characters from anywhere in the filename works very well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I can't speak for others (e.g., `zsh`) but if you are using `bash`,
wildcards do work to an extent. 
Example:

```
~ $ ls
Documents
Desktop
Downloads
```

If you use an asterisk (`*`), you get:

```
~ $ cd *ments
~/Documents $
```

That's because `bash` can do the substitutions before the command ever gets to `cd`.

In the case of `cd`, if multiple matches work, you would expect the behaviour to be undefined:

```
~ $ cd *s
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

`bash` expands this to `cd Documents Downloads`,
which doesn't make sense to `cd`.

---

You can also rely on `bash`'s autocomplete.  In your example, you can simply type `cd t`; then hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will auto-complete to: `cd this.is.` or whatever the next ambiguous character is.  Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> a second time to see all options in this filtered set.

You can repeat by entering another character to narrow it down,
<kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete to the next ambiguous character,
and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see all options.

---

Going further, `bash` can handle wildcards in autocomplete.  In the first case above, you can type `cd D*s` then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get suggestions of what could match the pattern:

```
~ $ cd D*s
Documents/ Downloads/
~ $ cd D*s
```

If only one match exists, it'll get completed for you.

```
~ $ cd *loads
~ $ cd Downloads/
```

---

You could also use `ls` if you don't mind being in the questioned directory.  The `-d` tells `ls` to list directories themselves instead of their contents.

```
$ ls -d *long*
this.is.very.long.name.context
this.is.another.long.path.authors
```

or you could use `find` if you want to look recursively:

```
$ find workspace -type d -name '*long*'
workspace/this.is.very.long.name.context
workspace/this.is.another.long.path.authors
```

Comment: "I can't speak for others (e.g. `zsh`)" while zsh has the same behavior here, it also gets rid of the problem entirely by autocompleting anywhere in the string, not just the beginning.

Comment: Note that "ls *long*" will display the contents of any directories, not the directory names themselves. "ls -d *long*" will give the output suggested here.

Comment: Adding to bash's autocomplete: You can also type `cd *word*<TAB>` and bash will autocomplete to the first entry (in directory order, I assume) matching that pattern (no list of options popping up here, sadly).

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`, you can configure the completion system with `zstyle`s so it complete words in the middle.

The `compinstall` function can assist you with that. Run it as `autoload compinstall; compinstall` for instance. It's also available through the `zsh-newuser-install` menu often invoked upon first use of `zsh` (when you don't have a `.zshrc` yet).

```
               *** compinstall: main menu ***
2.  Matching control: set behaviour for case-insensitive matching,
    extended (partial-word) matching and substring matching.
```

```
              *** compinstall: matcher menu ***

`Matchers' compare the completion code with the possible matches in some
special way.  Numbers in parentheses show matchers to be tried and the order.
The same number can be assigned to different matchers, meaning apply at the
same time.  Omit a sequence number to try normal matching at that point.
A `+' in the first line indicates the element is added to preceding matchers
instead of replacing them; toggle this with `t'.  You don't need to set
all four, or indeed any matchers --- then the style will not be set.

   (    )   `+' indicates add to previous matchers, else replace
n. (    ) No matchers; you may want to try this as the first choice.
c. (    ) Case-insensitive completion (lowercase matches uppercase)
C. (    ) Case-insensitive completion (lower/uppercase match each other)
p. (    ) Partial-word completion:  expand 'f.b' to 'foo.bar', etc., in one go.
          You can choose the separators (here `.') used each time.
s. (    ) Substring completion:  complete on substrings, not just initial
          strings.  Warning: it is recommended this not be used for element 1.
```

If you make it just:

```
   (    )   `+' indicates add to previous matchers, else replace
n. (1   ) No matchers; you may want to try this as the first choice.
c. (    ) Case-insensitive completion (lowercase matches uppercase)
C. (    ) Case-insensitive completion (lower/uppercase match each other)
p. (    ) Partial-word completion:  expand 'f.b' to 'foo.bar', etc., in one go.
          You can choose the separators (here `.') used each time.
s. ( 2  ) Substring completion:  complete on substrings, not just initial
          strings.  Warning: it is recommended this not be used for element 1.
```

and save and exit, you'll see `compinstall` added this line to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' '' '' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
```

`info zsh matcher-list` (note: you may need to install a `zsh-doc` package) will tell you how that works.

Then if you type `cd ano`<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you'll see it being completed to `this.is.another.long.path.authors` assuming there's no file whose name starts with `ano`.

I invite you to go through all the `compinstall` menus as there's a lot more amazing features in there you can enable. (same for `zsh-newuser-install`).

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste the part that you need.

Answer (score -1):

Use a backslash. This is an escape character, which tells the computer to treat the space literally. Here is an example:

```
cd My\ Documents
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is not asking about whitespace in path names nor escaping.

Comment: Welcome, @Bitecofer!  You will likely get down-voted because your response does not answer the OP, even though it is relevant to using a `cd` command and is helpful in some contexts.  You will notice that the OP doesn't have spaces in their example directory names and thus your response is not helpful in this instance. Again, welcome to the platform and may you bless others and be blessed through it.

Comment: @Bitecofer, also, if you delete your response after it has been downvoted, you will get a badge--something called "Peer Pressure" or something like that.  I learned that through experience. ;)